# How can I change the style of several classes that end with the same name?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a series of elements in different React components to which I want to modify "dynamically" the padding.
Let's imagine that I have the following:

```
<div className="blue-content">
<div className="menu-black">
<div className="big-content">
<div className="red-content">
```

*I do not always know the complete className

**how could I via CSS or Javascript change the style of all the ones ending with "content"?**

Comment: Easily: `[class$="-content"]` { ... } with the [w3schools: CSS attribute$=value Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp)

Comment: Check out the MDN for attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 1):

**CSS Way:**

Just add the used attribute name at the beginning which follows `[class$='-content']`

**Like this example below, where i am using a div as a selector:**

```css
div[class$='-content']{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-content"> test </div>
<div class="x-content"> test1 </div>
<div class="y-content"> test2 </div>
<div class="z-content"> test3 </div>
```

**Further Explaination:**

> You could use $= to select className end with specific string.

**or**

> Use *= to match any className contain this string.

**Like here (`*=` example):**

```css
div[class*='-content']{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-content"> test </div>
<div class="x-content-abc"> test1 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute selector. `$=` may be use to match the end of the attribute. Try:

```css
div[class$='-content'] {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-content"></div>
<div class="menu-black"></div>
<div class="big-content"></div>
<div class="red-content"></div>
```

Just in case you need to match the start of the attribute, you may use `attribute^=start`